# new Facebook SDK 4 throw exception about PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE in laravel

Tags: facebook, laravel-4, facebook-php-sdk

I wanted implement the new facebook API v 4.0.0 on my project laravel.

Setting all the necessary informations and credentials for access to my app, when is time to call the function for the login:

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://mywebsite.dev');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
```

It throw me an exception

> FacebookSDKException 'Session not active, could not store state.'

So I dig in to the SDK class of facebook on that line and there is a check about session precisely this one:

```
 if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
      throw new FacebookSDKException(
        'Session not active, could not store state.'
      );
    }
```

Then I didn't know why this happen so i tried to put the same check on a clean route and see the result

```
Route::get('test',function() {

   if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
    {
        return "is not active";
    }

    return "is active";

});
```

And it return `is not active` why this happen? in this way I cannot use the new facebook API with laravel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve extending that class and overwriting the following 2 methods that require native sessions.

```
    protected function storeState($state)
    {
        Session::put('facebook.state', $state);
    }

    protected function loadState()
    {
        return $this->state =  Session::get('facebook.state');
    }
```

Comment: Where did you extend the class though? In a new controller?

Comment: No, I was creating a package for the Fb API and I created a new class with this 2 methods and I extended the original class with this one. But you shouldn't need to do it. I saw on the fb API on github that has been implemented a injector, that you can inject your custom session driver. :)

Comment: did you inject laraval session driver? if please give an example

Comment: No, I just extended the class responsible for the session and overwritten that 2 methods. But i guess that with the new updates it can be injected

Comment: Details of where to create this new class and how to invoke it in your code - http://laravel.io/forum/07-24-2014-implement-facebookredirectloginhelper-problem

Answer (score 13):

Sharing how I implemented Facebook SDK V4 on Laravel 4.

Here's what I added on default composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4" : {
        "Facebook\\":"vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/"
    }
},
```

Added Facebook initialization on my index.php, like this :

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Initialized Facebook PHP SDK V4
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
*/

//Initialize
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(Config::get('facebook.AppId'),Config::get('facebook.AppSecret'));
```

And for the Session, Laravel doesn't use $_SESSION so you don't need to do session_start at all. For you to be able to use Laravel session on Facebook PHP SDK V4, you need to extend Facebook's *FacebookRedirectLoginHelper* class.
Here's how how to subclass  *FacebookRedirectLoginHelper* and overwrite Session handling.

```
class LaravelFacebookRedirectLoginHelper extends \Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
{

  protected function storeState($state)
  {
    Session::put('state', $state);
  }

  protected function loadState()
  {
    $this->state = Session::get('state');
    return $this->state;
  }


  protected function isValidRedirect()
  {

    return $this->getCode() && Input::has('state')
        && Input::get('state') == $this->state;

  }



  protected function getCode()
  {
    return Input::has('code') ? Input::get('code') : null;
  }


  //Fix for state value from Auth redirect not equal to session stored state value
  //Get FacebookSession via User access token from code
  public function getAccessTokenDetails($app_id,$app_secret,$redirect_url,$code)
  {

        $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
          . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_url
          . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);

        return $params;
   }


}
```

And one more step, you need to do a composer command to regenerate autoload files :

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Ok, if all goes right, you are now ready to start using the SDK, here's a sample

Here's an excerpt from one of my project classes :

```
namespace Fb\Insights;

//Facebook Classes
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;


//Our Facebook Controller
use FbController;

class PagePosts extends \Facebook\GraphObject {

    /*
        Get Page Posts Impression
        https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/insights#post_impressions     


    */
    public static function getPagePostsImpressions($postid = null) {

        $fbctrl = new FbController();

        $metricNames = array(
            'post_impressions',
            'post_impressions_unique',
            'post_impressions_paid',
            'post_impressions_paid_unique',
            'post_impressions_fan',
            'post_impressions_fan_unique',
            'post_impressions_fan_paid',
            'post_impressions_fan_paid_unique',
            'post_impressions_organic',
            'post_impressions_organic_unique',
            'post_impressions_viral',
            'post_impressions_viral_unique',
            'post_impressions_by_story_type',
            'post_impressions_by_story_type_unique',
            'post_impressions_by_paid_non_paid',
            'post_impressions_by_paid_non_paid_unique'
        );

        $postsInsights = array();       
        $batch = array();
        $limit = $fbctrl->FacebookGraphDateLimit();     


        //craft our batch API call
        for($i=0; $i<count($metricNames); $i++) {       
            $batch[] = json_encode(array('method' => 'GET','relative_url' => $postid . '/insights/' . $metricNames[$i] . '?since=' . $limit['since'] . '&until=' . $limit['until'] ));
        }
        $params = array( 'batch'    => '[' . implode(',',$batch ) . ']' );      

        $session = new FacebookSession($fbctrl->userAccessToken);

        try {

            $res = (new FacebookRequest($session,'POST','/',$params))
                ->execute()
                ->getGraphObject();

        } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
            //log this error
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        } catch(\Exception $ex) {
            //log this error
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }

        //Collect data
        for($i=0; $i<count($batch); $i++) {

            $resdata = json_decode(json_encode($res->asArray()[$i]),true);

            $fbctrl->batchErrorDataChecker($resdata,$postsInsights,$metricNames[$i]);

        }

        return $postsInsights;

    }
```

Feel free comment or suggest so I can also improve my code.
Happy coding.

Comment: How does your `FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(Config::get('facebook.AppId'),Config::get('facebook.AppSecret'));` work if you're not using PHP sessions?

Comment: After extending it, how do I make sure Laravel is calling it without editing the vendor folders?

Answer (score 4):

I used follow steps using Composer and had problem "Session not active, could not store state" so session_start() fixed my issue.

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

session_start();
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('apid', 'appscret');
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("callbackurl", $apiVersion = NULL);
try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
}
if (isset($session)) {

    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    var_dump($graphObject);
} else {
    echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve problem call `session_start` php function after to inizialize `FacebookRedirectLoginHelper` somthing like this:

> session_start();
>
> $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://mywebsite.dev');
>
> $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();

Comment: I don't wanna use native sessions

Answer (score 0):

kaixersoft's answer really saved my bacon a little while ago, and I got everything to work by following his instructions using the custom LaravelFacebookRedirectLoginHelper class. But today I went to do a 'composer update' and for some reason, it broke everything. I've modified kaixersoft's LaravelFacebookRedirectLoginHelper class so that it works now, specifically the isValidRedirect method. Here is the updated class:

```
class LaravelFacebookRedirectLoginHelper extends \Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
{

  protected function storeState($state)
  {
    Session::put('state', $state);
  }

  protected function loadState()
  {
    $this->state = Session::get('state');
    return $this->state;
  }


  protected function isValidRedirect()
  {
    $savedState = $this->loadState();
    if (!$this->getCode() || !isset($_GET['state'])) {
      return false;
    }
    $givenState = $_GET['state'];
    $savedLen = mb_strlen($savedState);
    $givenLen = mb_strlen($givenState);
    if ($savedLen !== $givenLen) {
      return false;
    }
    $result = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $savedLen; $i++) {
      $result |= ord($savedState[$i]) ^ ord($givenState[$i]);
    }
    return $result === 0;
  }



  protected function getCode()
  {
    return Input::has('code') ? Input::get('code') : null;
  }


  //Fix for state value from Auth redirect not equal to session stored state value
  //Get FacebookSession via User access token from code
  public function getAccessTokenDetails($app_id,$app_secret,$redirect_url,$code)
  {

        $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
          . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . $redirect_url
          . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);

        return $params;
   }


}
```

Answer (score -2):

session_status function is available on (PHP >=5.4.0) version. So if you are using older version of PHP then Please update it Or Just

```
 // change this 

 if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {

      throw new FacebookSDKException(
        'Session not active, could not store state.'
      );
    }



//into this

if(session_id() === "") {

    throw new FacebookSDKException(
        'Session not active, could not load state.'
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is no the best option. Because I cannot edit the source of the package other ways on composer update i'll loose the changes